# No User Prompt on Serial Console

Tags: systemd, serial-console, solus

I am trying to enable the serial console on my SystemD VM so I can get in to it via the console, but when connecting it is not letting me select the user.

Reading through the [serial console documentation](http://www.0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html) it seems that I only need to add `console=ttyS0` to the `COMMAND_LINE_LINUX` section of grub, and SystemD will automatically start listening for serial connections.

When connecting to the system via `virsh console {system_id}` it outputs:

```
$ sudo virsh console 1
Password:
```

With no user prompt.
I tried the user's password, and setting a root password but nothing seems to be working.
I tried setting up the serial terminal manually and setting autologin to the user:

```
systemctl enable serial-getty@ttyS0
```

Editing the agetty line to `add --autologin user`, but no effect.

I saw [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169935/no-login-prompt-on-serial-console) question and confirmed that my kernel config should have `CONFIG_FHANDLE=Y` though I can't find the config file locally to verify, only in their repository.

Any ideas how I can get the serial console working?

Answer (score 3):

This was another case of "I am an idiot".

I think I was mistaking my sudo password prompt for the VM user login...

Anyhow after rebuilding the machine the full steps to enable the serial console on Solus:

Client:

```
systemctl enable serial-getty@ttyS0
systemctl start serial-getty@ttyS0
```

Host:

```
sudo virsh console {system_id}
```

Making sure to type in your Host's sudo password, and you are done.

Interestingly I had to do it this way instead of just adding the Grub command line option, haven't figured out why yet.